# Octobercms Translate plugin - defaul language for backend admin

Tags: localization, octobercms

know somebody if it is possible set default language for editing of static pages and menu for for each admin individually?

For example:

admin1 first user: defautly manage static pages a menu in czech

admin2 other user: defautly manage static pages a menu in english

[image: Default language by admin]

thank you

Vaclav

Comment: if those users are working simultaneously then it's not possible. for other scenario at login we can change default lang based on user

Comment: Yes, sorry admin1 is one user and admin2 is other user. I can change backend preferences user language, but the change of language will not change the static page language. Or do you mean some other solution?

Comment: Hmm, problem here with the default lang is its stores in DB. so changing that will affect all users

Comment: And is there any way to solve it, or is it just a thought?

Comment: it was just thought